# Control not visible after toggling visibility recursively?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, toggle, visibility

### A Quick Note

I've tried to be as thorough as possible with my question but you may still need additional clarification; if this happens to be the case, feel free to comment your concerns and I will update the post to answer them as best as I can.

---

I came across a rather odd issue yesterday when toggling controls on my form. I have a period of loading on `FormShown` and all controls but the loading display should be hidden. The toggle works to turn visibility off for everything but the loading display, but when loading completes only some of the controls are visible.

I stepped through the code that turns everything back to visible and ensured that everything is indeed being set to `Visible = true`. I think it may have something to do with the `Dock` property on the controls, or maybe the `TabIndex` or something similar but I'm having trouble tracking the underlying issue down.

This is the code I use to toggle the control visibility:

```
private void ToggleAllControlVisibility() {
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
        ToggleControlVisibility(c);
}
private void ToggleControlVisibility(Control c) {
    if (c.Name == "loadingContainer")
        return;

    if (!(c is SplitContainer || c is SplitterPanel))
        c.Visible = !c.Visible;

    foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
        ToggleControlVisibility(child);
}
```

It is a recursive toggle in which all child controls are also toggled. The `ToggleAllControlVisibility` method is called before loading begins, and again after loading completes.

---

### A More Detailed Look

Now that you know the problem, there are certain controls in particular that I know do not show (at least the way they should). Take the following control tree for example:

- pTimePanel (Panel)

  - timeSlider (TrackBar)
  - lblStartTime (Label)
  - lblStopTime (Label)

Out of the controls above, only the `pTimePanel` actually displays in the foreground. I believe its child controls may be displaying behind it somehow because as I step through the code and it reaches the `lblStartTime` control, I can briefly see the outline of the label (no content) and then when it moves to the next control it's gone. The `timeSlider` control doesn't seem to show the same behavior but it does get back to `Visible = true`.

The full tree from form to the above controls (with docking properties) is as below:

```
splitContainer : Dock-Fill
    panel1 (SplitterPanel)
        loadingPanel (Panel) : Dock-Fill
        pTimePanel (Panel) : Dock-Bottom
            pTimeLabels (Panel) : Dock-Bottom
                lblStartTime (Label) : Dock-Left
                lblStopTime (Label) : Dock-Right
            timeSlider (TrackBar) : Dock-Fill
```

---

### Notes

Some of these may be less helpful than others, but as I think of things that may help clarify what's going on, I'll add them here.

- When visibility is toggled in either direction, the `Resize` event on the `loadingPanel` is raised.

---

### Question

What could possibly be occurring to make this odd behavior possible?

Comment: Are you sure that `timeSlider` is inside `pTimePanel` and not hiding behind `timeSlider`?

Comment: For this sort of problem, I often find that it helps to try to recreate it in a very simple new project. Either building up from nothing towards the real code, or starting with a copy of the real code and cutting things out. If you can do that, and post the sample, people will have a go at debugging it for you.

Comment: @RobinBennett That is a very good idea, and I've thought about rebuilding the form to ensure everything is where it should be and having another go, but I figured I would see if anyone else has encountered a similar issue since with more simple forms I've never seen it. I'm thinking that perhaps I just added something in the wrong order.

Comment: Could toggling the visibility of a parent control toggle the visibility of its children? In this case I would not toggle but explicitly set the visibility to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I assume you mean `timeSlider` is inside `pTimePanel` not behind `pTimePanel`? If so, then it follows the structure described above telling me that `timeSlider` is indeed a child control of `pTimePanel`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I tried that too, I added a `bool` to the method to ensure that on the first call everything was set to `false` and on the second everything was set to `true`, same thing occurred.

Comment: Maybe it would help to not apply the toggling recursively, but instead, to only toggle the visibility of the top level controls, except for the `loadingContainer`. I also would test `c == loadingContainer`. This is safer than relying on the name.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'll give that a go and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was related to the order in which the controls were added to the form. Due to some copying and pasting controls a while back things ended up in an improper order. I had to rebuild the form from scratch to get any toggling to actually work. Once I rebuilt the form, all of the available options for toggling began working the way I expected them to.